# The lion and the zebras

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, euclidean-geometry, game-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

The lion plays a deadly game against a group of $N$ zebras that takes place in the steppe (= an infinite plane). The lion starts in the origin with coordinates $(0,0)$, while the $N$ zebras may arbitrarily pick their starting positions. The lion and the group of zebras move alternately:

- In a lion move, the lion moves from its current position to a position at most 1 unit away.
- In the zebras move, *one of the zebras* moves from its current position to a position at most 1 unit away.

The lion wins if for any $\varepsilon\gt 0$, it can get within $\varepsilon$ of a zebra in finite number of moves. Otherwise the zebras win.

There're only 2 possibilities:

1. Zebras win for all $N\geq 1 $.
2. $\exists M$, such that lion wins for all $N\geq M$.

Which possibility is true? (Heuristics are welcome too)

---

**Source:** I found this lovely little game from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9097/the-lion-and-the-zebras-ii-the-lion-with-millimeter-long-claws), where the case for $N=100$ is discussed but remains inconclusive. You may also want to check [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/9078/68538), where the zebras have been shown to have a winning strategy if the $\varepsilon$ requirement is dropped (i.e. the lion needs to actually catch a zebra to win instead of just getting within $\varepsilon$ to it).

---

***Edited*** the question following Ycor's advice in the comment.

Comment: Obviously the number $N$ of zebras and the distance (which can be renormalized) are unrelated. So we have one game for each $N$, and one can wonder about small values of $N$ ($N=100$ has no particular significance). For $N=1$ obviously the zebras win. For $N=2$ too (zebras start opposite at distance $>1$[hm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hectometre).

Comment: similar question with a 400 reputation bounty at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/9155

Comment: @YCor That's true. I copied the puzzle in its original form. It's large $N$ that we are interested in. Not too difficult to show that zebras win for $N=3$, too. So either there's a magical $N$ from which on the lion suddenly wins, or the trend continues and zebras always win.

Comment: But, if you want to elaborate a strategy for the lion, I don't think you will solve the problem for large $N$ without dealing with small $N$. For instance the strategy to eat the zebra at time $n$ consists in being with distance $\le 1$ of 2 zebras at time $n-1$, which in turn involves something with 3 zebras some little time before, etc. Actually I guess that the lion wins over 4 zebras, and this should come with a good understanding of the $N=3$ case (e.g., even if the lion can't win over 3 zebras, it can probably manage the shape of the triangle they form to become roughly equilateral).

Comment: Here is a game in a similar setting (but probably with very different underlying ideas): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_problem

Comment: @YCor "For instance the strategy to eat the zebra at time  consists in being with distance ≤1 of 2 zebras at time −1, which in turn involves something with 3 zebras some little time before, etc." That's probably not true. Zebras can adopt strategies so that the lion may never be able to fork 2 of them at once. Yet the lion has a strategy to win nonetheless. As evidenced [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10069/68538).

Comment: Evidently, Eric, you know a lot more about this puzzle than you've included in your question. This leads to people wasting their time, and yours, telling you things you already know. I think you should edit your question to summarize what's already known about the puzzle.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I genuinely know very little beyond the source I included in the question, from which my comments also originate. Even the $N=3$ case is a heuristic that I've not pinned down as a proof yet. I'll definitely update the question when I've got something worth to say.

Comment: Maybe we can prove by induction that for any number of zebra $N$, they can win. Maybe from a distant $d_N$ they always have a strategy, even if they are all on the same point of the plan, and without even going outside certain area $A_N$  of the plan ,kind of a non compact  area betwin two curves, so that $A_N\subset A_{N+1}$. The idea is that if the lion is outside $A_N$ the zebras can even stop moving.  Then if $d_n$ is great enough compare to $d_{n-1}$ one single zebra would have to move untill the edge of $A_{N+1}$ such that we are back to the $N-1$ case.

Comment: And it would be about sizing wisely $A_N$ and $d_n$...

Comment: may be try  the situation where each zebra stay in an angular sector (both side the lines) for some wise initial configuration,  and it might work for  infinily many zebras... i'm trying to fix something, but not very confident^^

Comment: oh ... why not combining the two ideas : one zebra strategy like in the last comment, where polar coordinates of zebras increase same way, in a wise way, and one strategy when the zebra  are in a small angle of vision , or at least all far enought from lion .. with kind of an hope that when case one is problematic , then case two is applyable, and receprocally

Comment: Let me try an heuristic :  assign to each zebra a  **semi-line containing O**,  to escape  lion that would be closer to O than the zebra  (we considere infinitely many zebra so that first zebras configuration still holds, for easier induction) AND **all parralleles escape semi-lines** (wich also depends on  lion) in case the lion is getting closer to O when aporoaching the  zebra. we can make wlog the concentric area small  enought to get some *place* to escape parallelly, by making arbitrary big initial distances to O, which might also give zebra some *time* to escape wrt $\epsilon$

Comment: Sorry for the accumulation but thinking we can iterate the process in case the lion find a strategy to park zebra  (sort of infinitally many concentrics areas that provides place... ) simultaneoussly, as a possible (non exclusive) alternative , i just had the idea that the lines can be fonction of the configuration, and not fixed, and that maybe,( more and more simple), **variating strips** could solve the puzzle without much sophistication...

Comment: To finish the monologue in a different type of idea, maybe we have missed one eventuality : that neither the zebras neither the lion has a wining strategy.  Maybe a strategy wich is not worse then any other, consists for both side, in choosing with a dice witch way to go, so that the lion would win if he's lucky and loose if he's not!

Comment: @jcdornano That can't happen. Either the lion or the zebras have a winning strategy.

Comment: @Eric : is-it something complicated to proove or do you have an obviouss argument that i don't clearly yet see?

Answer (score 9):

### Zebras win for all $N$.

I didn't realize Lawrence's answer in the source is actually sound (or so I think, when I really took some time to read it through this morning). Below I basically adopt Lawrence's strategy for $N$, with schematic drawings to make the argument easier to follow.

**The following is a winning starting position for the zebras.**

[image: starting position]

where $a$ is the distance, to be determined, at which the zebras are able to keep the lion away. Each lane is of width $4+2a$ with zebras horizontally centered.

**Strategy for the zebras:**

Each zebra mentally draws a square with itself at the center. We specify zebras' strategy to win in each possible situation below:

[image: zebra strategy]

1. If the lion is at the boarder or outside of the square, stay put.
2. As soon as the lion is inside the square but outside the $2a$ strip marked by the pair of dotted lines (boarder included), zebra move 1 unit vertically away from it.
3. As soon as the lion is inside the square and the strip of dotted lines, zebra move 1 unit vertically away from it.

The lion never wins by staying in Situation $1$ and $2$.

**Strategy under Situation $3$**

Situation 3 merits more analysis, because there the zebra can't keep going indefinitely without the lion closing in eventually. How far can it keep going before falling into the $a$ radius of the lion? The answer is that it can go at least as far as $L$, as shown below:

[image: situ3]

By Pythagorus, we have $L=1+\frac{1}{2a}$. Notice $L$ can be made as large as we want by adjusting $a$ accordingly. Of course $L$ has to be an integer by zebras' strategy stated above. Let's give a wide margin and say it can go at least as far as

$$L^{*}=L/2=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4a} \;\;\;\;\; (1)$$

Now the idea for a strategy in situation 3 is this: the zebra choose some point $s$ along its vertical escape path (of length $L^{*}$), at which it flees ***horizontally*** away from the lion. The point $s$ should be chosen so that all the other zebras are far away enough from this horizontal escape path. In that case, if the lion changes target during its horizontal pursuit, the escaper would be able to escape to the center of an unoccupied vertical lane before the lion reaches the new target's square, thereby forcing the game back to situation $1$.

How can this be achieved? Notice to escape to the center of the nearest unoccupied lane, a zebra will have to cross a distance at most $N(4+2a)$. Let's take

$$L^{*}=2N(N(4+2a)+2+2a) \;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

Then by the pigeonhole principle, there exists $s$ along the vertical escape path whose nearest vertical distance to another zebra is at least $\frac{L^{*}}{2N}=N(4+2a)+2+2a$. If the zebra turns and flees horizontally at this $s$, the lion will be at least $N(4+2a)$ away vertically from any other zebra's square, as shown below.

[image: horizontal escape]

And we're done! If the lion keeps its horizontal chasing, the zebra just keeps running. The horizontal distance between the pair will always be greater than $1/2$ (by $(1)$). If the lion switches target during this chase, it can't reach its new target's square before the old target reaches the center of an unoccupied vertical lane, as shown above.

Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives

$$a= \frac{\sqrt{256N^4 + 256N^3 + 48N^2 +1} + 1 - 16N^2 - 8N}{16(N^2 + N)}$$

The lion will not be able to get within this radius of any zebra.

---

If my calculation below is correct, by widening the lane (and enlarging the squares accordingly), the zebras can keep the lion at arbitrarily large distance. Let's take the size of the lane and squares to be $2k+2a$, equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ becomes

$$L^{*}=\frac{(a + k - 1)^2 - a^2}{4a}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (1)'$$

$$L^{*}=2N(N(2k+2a)+k+2a)\;\;\;(2)'$$

Solving $(1)'$ and $(2)'$ for $a$ we have

$$a=\frac{\sqrt{q} + k - 8kN^2 -4kN  - 1}{16N(N + 1)}$$

where

$$q= 64k^2N^4 + 64k^2N^3 + 16k^2N^2 + 8k^2N + k^2 - 16kN^2 - 24kN - 2k + 16N^2 + 16N + 1$$

Clearly, $\displaystyle{\lim_{k \to \infty} a(N,k) = \infty}$.

So it seems this game is really skewed to the zebras' side.